# apache poi get paragraph relative to other table or paragraph

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache poi, I'm processing a ms word document that contains an arbitrary number of tables scattered throughout the document with no standardized structure.

```
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p <--- this specific paragraph contains some useful information
w:p
w:p
w:tbl <--- this is the table I'm going to work with
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:p
w:tbl
w:p
```

The information contained within an arbitrary table must be supplemented using some information in a paragraph situated above the table's dom position.

I'd like to run something like

```
for each table in the document
    check above paragraphs until a condition is met
    use that paragraph to do something
```

So far, the only relationship between dom node positions in relation with each other is reachable through something like `org.w3c.dom.Node node = table.getCTTbl().getDomNode();` in which case it's relatively difficult to get a bijective object chain like `table -> CTTbl -> node > lookup routine > otherNode > cTP > paragraph`

This seems too simple of a problem for it not to have some existing functionality I'm not aware of.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of tables which are contained in the Word document and need to get the paragraphs above each table, then following could be done:

- Get the text body where the table is in.
- Get the body elements of that text body.
- Determine the index of the table in that body elements list.
- Loop backwards through the body elements from that index on and get
  paragraphs until you find the interesting paragraph or another table
  or end at the begin.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List;

public class WordReadTablesAndParagraphsAbove {
    
 static void getParagraphsAbove(XWPFTable table) {
  List<IBodyElement> bodyElements = table.getBody().getBodyElements();
  int indexInBodyElementList = bodyElements.indexOf(table); // get index of that table in body elements
  for (int i = indexInBodyElementList -1; i >=0; i--) { // loop backwards through body elements
   IBodyElement bodyElement = bodyElements.get(i);
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) { // we have a XWPFParagraph
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    // is this the interesting paragraph?
    System.out.println(paragraph + ":" + paragraph.getText());
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable) { // we have another table
    break;
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordDocumentSample.docx"));

  for (XWPFTable table : document.getTables()) {
   System.out.println(table);
   getParagraphsAbove(table);
  }
  
  document.close();
 }
}
```

But the whole thing smells like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why not traversing all body elements in document top down using [XWPFDocument.getBodyElements](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getBodyElements--)? There look for the interesting paragraph. Then the table for that will be the next table in body elements list.